# VBA Excel - Insert Picture with Url - Credentials Window

Tags: excel, vba, image

I have a macro set up to navigate through a website and scrape data + images to create a product comparison list. The small issue i'm having is that when trying to insert a picture using VBA i sometimes get a windows security prompt window to insert login details. If i cancel the window, the code works correctly but having this pop-up every product in a range of 50 items isn't ideal.

I've found a few image url's that seem to insert without this pop-up showing, which suggests to me that it's to do with how secure microsoft see's the website.
I've also tried both .Pictures.Insert and .Shapes.AddPicture. Both have the same issue

The code below using the first link will show the login window, but if you use the second link it will work without a pop-up

```
Sub DrawPicture()
Dim link As String
link = "https://2ecffd01e1ab3e9383f0-07db7b9624bbdf022e3b5395236d5cf8.ssl.cf4.rackcdn.com/Product-190x190/0e72ef05-691d-4b3b-b978-a1bb9929e372.jpg"
'link = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/54789364/JPG-logo-highres.jpg"
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert (link)
End Sub
```

If someone could explain and provide a solution to this issue that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim src         As String
Dim lfn         As String

src = "https://2ecffd01e1ab3e9383f0-07db7b9624bbdf022e3b5395236d5cf8.ssl.cf4.rackcdn.com/Product-190x190/0e72ef05-691d-4b3b-b978-a1bb9929e372.jpg"
lfn = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Output.jpg"

If RequestDownload(src, lfn) Then
    Cells(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert lfn
End If
End Sub

Function RequestDownload(URL$, FILE$) As Boolean
Dim b()         As Byte
Dim f           As Integer

With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .setRequestHeader "DNT", "1"
    On Error GoTo Fin
    .send

    If .Status = 200 Then
        b = .responseBody
        f = FreeFile(1)
        Open FILE For Binary As #f
        Put #f, , b
        Close #f
        RequestDownload = True
    End If
Fin:
End With
End Function
```

Comment: That seems to work, however i'd prefer not to download each picture into the folder.

Comment: Is there a way to use this work around without having to download the image into the folder?

Comment: You may delete the image using Kill after downloading and inserting into the worksheet ..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the DisplayAlerts setting to Flase?

```
Sub DrawPicture()
Dim link As String
link = "https://2ecffd01e1ab3e9383f0-07db7b9624bbdf022e3b5395236d5cf8.ssl.cf4.rackcdn.com/Product-190x190/0e72ef05-691d-4b3b-b978-a1bb9929e372.jpg"
'link = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/54789364/JPG-logo-highres.jpg"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert (link)
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I hadn't but that doesn't seem to fix the issue. Thanks for the idea though